# Error while statements

Tags: java, while-loop, numberformatexception

I'm trying to make a statement that when you enter an integer terminates. I can only make one that continues with an integer. I was also considering trying to catch the specific error witch is the `NumberFormatExeption` except I am not good enough to figure that out
Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.lang.NumberFormatException;

public class Calc_Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException{
    while(true){
        String INT= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number here: ");
        int Int = Integer.parseInt(INT);
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, Int);
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

[EDIT]
I cleaned up my code some and came up with this with the help of my friends on stack overflow. Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Calc_Test {
public static void main(String[] args){
    while(true){
        String inputInt= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number here: ");
        if(inputInt.matches("-?\\d+")){
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "\"" + inputInt + "\"" + " is a number");
            break;
            }
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "\"" + inputInt + "\"" + " is not a number. Therefore, " + "\"" + inputInt + "\"" + " could not be parsed. Try again.");
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Go ahead and get good enough, it's not hard. You should be probably be catching it anyway.

Comment: @RexPRGMER: are negative numbers valid? Or numbers bigger than 2.2 billion?

Comment: Any number is the goal but we figured it out

Comment: @C.Lang I got good enough! I learned about how try/catch statements work

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`String#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) together with a simple regular expression to see if the input contains only digits:

```
while(true){
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number here: ");
    if (input.matches("-?\\d+")) {
        int intVal = Integer.parseInt(input);
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, intVal);
        break;
    }
}
```

The regular expression `-?\\d+` means *an optional minus sign, followed by one or more digits*. You can read more on regular expressions in the Java Tutorials [Regular Expressions section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Note that I have changed your variable names to start with lower-case letters, to follow Java naming standards.

Comment: @RexPRGMER: Added an explanation and a link with further reading.

Comment: This regex does not allow negative numbers

Comment: @DanielPereira: True. Change to `"-?\\d+"` to allow negative numbers.

Comment: @DanielPereira Wait, How did you get "-?"?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put it into a `try/catch` block. Also, try to give a better name to your variables. Here's a example of how you can do it:

```
while (true) {
    String rawValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number here: ");
    try {
        int intValue = Integer.parseInt(rawValue);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, intValue);
        break;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You didn't type a number");
    }
}
```

Comment: I made this on my own a little later on but I want it to repeat if it is not an int